# to filter the rdlc report data according to parameter passed in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rdlc

```
Try
Dim ed As New Editor()
Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LMS ;Integrated Security=True")
con.Open()
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from Editor", con)

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(ed, "DataTable1")
con.Close()
End Using

ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc")
Dim parReportParam1 As New ReportParameter("Parameter1", Me.txtLan.Text.ToString())
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {
  parReportParam1
})
Dim datasource As New ReportDataSource("Editor", ed.Tables(0))
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

I am not able to get any data from my data set it is showing empty report viewer after adding parameter to report.rdlc

Answer (score 1):

```js
 Protected Sub bSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles bSubmit.Click
 ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc")
 Dim ed As New Editor()
 Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LMS ;Integrated Security=True")
 con.Open()
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from Editor where ([Language] = @Lang)", con)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lang", txtLan.Text)
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
 da.Fill(ed, "DataTable1")
 con.Close()
 End Using
 Dim datasource As New ReportDataSource("Editor", ed.Tables(0))
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
 End Sub
 End Class
```